# visual studio code saves cobol with strange characters

Tags: visual-studio-code, cobol

When I first started using Visual Studio Code for my cobol, it was working fine. But lately when I try to compile my code after saving it in vsc it gives errors about there being weird characters.

If I do the same changes in Notepad++ it works fine. I've been going through the settings in vsc but I cannot find anything wrong in there. But then again I don't know that much about it. I'm also using the extension cobol syntax support from bitlang.

Does anybody know how this is possible? Is there some setting that messes this up? I cannot really show any screens or anything. since this is all work related and I'm not allowed to share.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is, that this is related to the code page used to save the project.
Notepad++ by default uses UTF-8. you may need to change the code page on Visual Studio Code to UTF-8.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings